# How to prevent MnSymbols from aliasing \emptyset=\varnothing=\diameter?

Tags: fonts, symbols

I'd really like to keep the default `\emptyset`. I also use `MnSymbol`. But `MnSymbols` aliases `\emptyset` and `\varnothing` to `\diameter`.

How can I prevent that from happening? Could I save `\emptyset` previously to calling `\usepackage{MnSymbol}` and restore it later on?

Comment: I've marked your inline code with backticks `\``.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

please provide complete examples! And the package name is MnSymbol

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareSymbolFont{Symbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Emptyset}{\mathord}{Symbols}{"3B}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}

$\Emptyset$ $\emptyset$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, here one can do without a complete example, I think. But in general I fully agree!

Comment: Well, yes, but the answer is somewhat generic.

Comment: As I said, in general I fully agree! (I often ask people to provide complete examples.)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Though the empty set looks different then it looks without MnSymbol used at all. The \emptyset looks like a Stop-Sign, while the \MnEmptySet looks like a the \diameter sign. The regular \emptyset looks more oval.

Comment: @angerman: see edited example

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, I believe you could just explicitly change the empty set back to the cm empty set:

```
\renewcommand{\emptyset}{\font\cmsy = cmsy10 at 10pt
 \hbox{\cmsy \char 59}
}
```

I think the other solutions are better, however.